# How do you debug functions with postgres?

Tags: debugging, postgresql

I'm using pgAdmin III 1.8.4 and finding it a harsh mistress.

When writing stored procedures (functions), there's no query compilation. So I have no idea if my function will work until I call it.

How do other people work around this deficiency? (Other than getting it right first time :p)

Comment: You might try changing the title to be more clear that you're trying to debug stored procedures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EnterpriceDB` includes [**PL/PGSQL Debugger**](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products/postgres_plus_as/debugging.do) which you can use to step through the code.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look. I was thinking more process than a software solution.

Comment: Any way to see the values of temp tables while debugging?

Answer (score 2):

Write a unit test for it.  Granted this won't give you debugging capability, but you should ideally have a unit test suite (and an integration test suite) that you run against your code that proves that it works... and that lets you know when something breaks.

Comment: Fair point, but waiting until the data access code is up and running before knowing if the pgsql is even valid is more the issue here.

Comment: My thinking was along the lines of Test Driven Development & how loosely typed language writers deal with making sure stuff works.  Since most errors won't show up until run-time, they write a test suite to exercise their code.